# Basic HTML image and audio file not loading properly

Tags: html

I am not super fluent in html, css, or really any language as a matter of fact. I wrote a super basic website just for a little fun, however the image and audio file aren't loading at all. I really feel like everything is written as it should be, but I guess I'm wrong. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>THE GOAT</title>
</head>

<body>

<center>
 <img src="mango.jpg" />
 <br>
 <audio controls autoplay>
   <source src="falco.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The index.html is in the same folder as "mango.jpg" and "falco.mp3" so I don't think I need to make a more specific path. Here is the URL of the site:

[defaultfal.co](http://defaultfal.co)

Thanks for any help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I visit your image url directly, I get `403 forbidden`. This means that the permissions are set incorrectly on your server. (Specifically that the file is set to not be readable by the public.)

Make sure your file permissions are set to be readable by everyone! You can accomplish this using the `chmod` command line tool.

Edit: OP fixed it on his server and it works now!

Comment: @joetango the best way to thank someone is to accept their answer if it solved the issue.

Comment: @DylanB Can't accept an answer within 15mins of it being asked. I was going to politely ask him that, but not for another 5 minutes!

Comment: Yep I tried but told me to wait a bit, got it though!